# Abolish include-files in C++

Tags: c++, coding-style, include

Suppose i have the following code (literally) in a C++ source file:

```
// #include <iostream> // superfluous, commented-out
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I can compile this code even though `#include <iostream>` is commented-out:

```
g++ -include my_cpp_std_lib_hack source.cpp
```

Where my_cpp_std_lib_hack is a file in some central location that includes all the files of the C++ Standard Library:

```
#include <ciso646>
#include <climits>
#include <clocale>
...
#include <valarray>
#include <vector>
```

Of course, i can use proper compilation options for all compilers i care about (that being MS Visual Studio and maybe a few others), and i also use precompiled headers.

Using such a hack gives me the following advantages:

- Fast compilation (because all of the Standard Library is precompiled)
- No need to add `#include`s when all i want is adding some debugging output
- No need to remember or look up all the time where the heck `std::max` is declared
- A feeling that the STL is magically built-in to the language

So i wonder: am i doing something very wrong here?

Will this hack break down when writing large projects?

Maybe everyone else already uses this, and no one told me?

Comment: What if there are two headers that each define something with the same name?

Comment: I sincerely hate what you've done, but I am upvoting your question because I really want to see answers as to why exactly is this horrible

Comment: Actually, in a way, you tend to end up doing this in Visual C++. Its how the precompiled headers work. OK - stdafx.h is explicitly included (as opposed to this compiler-option hack), but it's still basically a huge list of everything you're app needs anywhere, even though most of it isn't needed in most places. As a result, a small change in one header tends to mean a large rebuild - since everything has a build dependency on stdafx.h. Kind of defeats the point, really.

Comment: @Steve314: But the difference with that is, if someone turns off precompilation, the entire project will still build (it will just be slower). With the OP's proposed solution, that would not be the case.

Comment: @Billy - agreed on "still build", but when I switched to cmake, I dropped all the precompiled headers and restructured the header files to avoid the worst excesses without wasting too much time. Typical build times improved a lot - several times faster on average, I'd say, since I have a lot of (template etc) code in header files - an accidental benefit, as the goal was to be able to build on either GCC or VC with minimal hassle.

Comment: @Steve314: Easiest way to have that work out of the box on both compilers is to use an ifdef -- `#include` the required headers anyway (even with stdafx.h`), and have `stdafx.h` become a no-op when some define for precompiled headers is turned off. Then you'll have fast compiles on both compilers. (Incidentally, this is what CryptoPP does)

Comment: @Steve314: Using precompiled headers *massively* speeds up compilation so it seems well worth it just for the minor hit of recompiling a lot of code if something stdafx.h references changes. Keeping in mind that stdafx.h should typically only include things which change very rarely (CRT, STL, SDK... stuff that changes maybe twice a year if that). You can also use more than one precompiled header if you wish to partition which things depend on, and will be recompiled as a result of changing, what.

Comment: There are people who don't use precompiled headers with C++? Woah.

Comment: @PiotrLegnica: Most POSIX projects I've seen don't precompile headers (namely because it's a much less publicized feature in GCC land).

Comment: @Leo - when you are careful to write re-usable code and to re-use it, you end up with a high library-to-app-code ratio. Since functions should be small, there are *many* small re-usable functions. Each particular library is rarely changed - but which bit will be maintained each day depends on what you're doing. *Something* is *always* changing. You can keep a header file out of stdafx.h as a dumping place for new stuff, which probably helps a bit, but that's not exactly putting things in the logical place, and you're saving hassles for later that way.

Comment: @Steve314: That's my point -- every one of your source files should be able to build as if stdafx.h was not included. However, it's not unreasonable to use it. Sure, things like iostream will get included twice, but when precompiled headers are on, the entire iostream header will simply be skipped by it's `pragma once` or `define` guard. When precompiled headers are off, stdafx becomes a no-op (best to do that with a define guard) and everything still builds efficiently. `stdafx.h` is not an excuse to stop paying attention to what you include. OTOH, it can massively speed up builds.

Comment: @Steve314: I still don't see your point. Re-compiling stdafx.h is (typically) a one-off hit per project. If you instead choose not to use stdafx.h then you get that hit *per file*. The hit may be slightly smaller per file than it is per project (since the files may include fewer files than stdafx.h) but the actual build time will be massively harmed. FWIW, I have a big library of reusable code and I don't put it into stdafx.h; that stuff compiles very quickly as it isn't *hundreds* of headers like the SDK/CRT/STL.

Comment: @Leo - I have a high percentage of local library use relative to standard libraries. If I'm not precompiling my own library headers, there isn't that much point. Mostly a history thing. And I still miss the old Borland `#pragma hdrstop` really. But remember I'm talking relative scales of things here. I'm not talking about some corporate library that takes hours to build - I'm talking about being so annoyed by the delay that I go and make a coffee. Libraries built up over time, but it's still one persons work.

Comment: *BUT* a typical build time in minutes became a typical build time in seconds for me. Obviously if my it-applies-more-widely is wrong then that was wrong, but my personal experience still stands.

Comment: Why exactly do you think that adding files to a precompiled header will give you faster compiles than **not including those files at all**? Even if your pch isn't recompiled, there's still a cost in including it, and that cost grows with the amount of code you're including in it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only thing "wrong" is that you are relying upon a compiler-specific command-line flag to make the files compilable. You'd need to do something different if not using GCC.  Most compilers probably do provide an equivalent feature, but it is best to write portable source code rather than to unnecessarily rely on features of your specific build environment.

Other programmers shouldn't have to puzzle over your Makefiles (or Ant files, or Eclipse workspaces, or whatever) to figure out how things are working.

This may also cause problems for users of IDE's. If the IDE doesn't know what files are being included, it may not be able to provide automatic completion, source browsing, refactoring, and other such features.

(FWIW, I do think it is a good idea to have one header file that includes all of the Standard Library headers that you are using in your project.  It makes precompilation easier, makes it easier to port to a non-standard environment, and also helps deal with those issues that sometimes arise when headers are included in different orders in different source files. But that header file should be *explicitly* included by each source file; there should be no magic.)

Comment: 7 years later, this is what I have been using for now, but it seems that clang cannot work this way, and *requires* putting pch-files in the `-include` on the command line or Makefile. According to [this](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#using-a-pch-file) user manual.

Answer (score 23):

> So i wonder: am i doing something very wrong here?

Yes. Sure, your headers are precompiled, but the compiler still has to do things like name lookups on the entire included mass of stuff which slows down compilation.

> Will this hack break down when writing large projects?

Yes, that's pretty much the problem. Plus, if anyone else looks at that code, they're going to be wondering where `std::cout` (well, assume that's a user defined type) came from. Without the `#include`s they're going to have no idea whatsoever.

Not to mention, now you have to link against a ton of standard library features that you may have (probably could have) avoided linking against in the first place.

If you want to use precompilation that's fine, but someone should be able to build each and every implementation file even when precompilation is disabled.

Comment: Never mind that this also breaks name lookup in editors like Vim.

Comment: And doesn't in editors like Eclipse ♪ (automatic setting discovery from build commands = huge win)... um, just mentioning. </fanboy>

Answer (score 4):

Forget the compilation speed-up - a precompiled header with templates isn't really "precompiled" except for the name and the parse, as far as I've heard. I won't believe in the compilation speed up until I see it in the benchmarks. :)

As for the usefulness:

I prefer to have an IDE which handles my includes for me (this is still bad for C++, but Eclipse already adds known includes with ctrl+shift+n with... well, acceptable reliability :)).

Comment: +1 -- true, but the "parse" is a *lot* of the work in C++ land.

Comment: @Billy: but not as much as the template instantiation. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Doing 'clandestine' includes like this would also make testing more difficult. You want to compile a smallest-possible subset of code when testing a particular component. Figuring out what that subset *is* would be difficult if the headers/sources aren't being honest about their dependencies, so you'd probably just drag your my_cpp_std_lib_hack into every unit test. This would increase compilation time for your test suites a *lot*. Established code bases often have more than three times as much test code as regular code, so this is likely to become an issue as your code base grows.

Answer (score 2):

From the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.1/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor%20Options):

> ```
> -include file
> ```
>
> Process file as if #include "file" appeared as the first line of the
>   primary source file. However, the
>   first directory searched for file is
>   the preprocessor's working directory
>   instead of the directory containing
>   the main source file. If not found
>   there, it is searched for in the
>   remainder of the #include "..." search
>   chain as normal.

So what you're doing is essentially equivalent to starting each file with the line

```
#include "my_cpp_std_lib_hack"
```

which is what Visual Studio does when it gathers up commonly-included files in `stdafx.h`. There are some benefits to that, as outlined by others, but your approach hides this include in the build process, so that nobody who looked directly at one of your source files would know of this hidden magic. Making your code opaque in this way does not seem like a good style to me, so if you're keen on all the precompiled header benefits I suggest you explicitly include your hack file.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something very wrong.  You are effectively including lots of headers that may not be needed.  In general, this is a very bad idea, because you are creating unnecessary dependencies, and a change in any header would require recompilation of everything.  Even if you are avoiding this by using precompiled headers, you are still linking to lots of object that you may not need, making your executable much larger than it needs to be.

There is really nothing wrong with the standard way of using headers.  You should include everything you are using, and no more (forward declarations are your friends).  This makes code easier to follow, and helps you keep dependencies under control.

Answer (score 0):

We try not to include the unused or even the rarely used stuff for example in VC++ there is

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN //exclude rarely used stuff
```

and what we hate in MFC is that if u want to make a simple application u will produce large executable file with the whole library (if statically linked), so it's not a good idea what if u only want to use the cout while the other no??

another thing i don't like to pass arguments via command line coz i may leave the project for a while, and forget what are the arguments... e.g. i prefer using

```
#pragma (comment, "xxx.lib")
```

than using it in command line, it reminds me at least with what file i want

That's is my own opinion make your code stable and easy to compile in order to to rot as code rotting is a very nasty thing !!!!!